# Posting error messages with many lines

Tags: support

I would like to post a question related to an error I am getting.
But the whole error message consists of approx. 200 lines and I am not sure which part is relevant from that.
Is there any other better option available that I should consider instead of posting this entire 200 lines as part of the question?

Comment: Do those 200 lines include a stack trace? Maybe that could be left out.

Comment: well, it includes some java thread dumps and I'am not sure whether I have to post it so that the readers will have better understanding of the question.

Comment: The most important thing about an error message is the error message. You could always add in the remaining lines if someone ass for it.

Comment: @penguin Begin with posting what you think is relevant, if it's not sufficient, we'll ask you to post more. Of course you shouldn't be guessing, try to do some research before posting the error.

Comment: I think most people just google the error message or code, so the error message, code, all the inner exceptions and their msgs and codes must be there.